# How to use "sire" as verb?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, sentence

How to use "sire" as verb?
Can you give also exempels?
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: and what does sire mean? That should be half the battle

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("no research/ELL"). Hi Hasan, did you consult a dictionary before you asked here? Our [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says "Be sure to [mention the research you've done](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5043) and what you're still hoping to learn!" For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: The OED provides no other verb meaning of "sire" than *To beget or procreate; to become the sire of:* said of both humans and animals - most notably racehorses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Sire is to refer to '[bring into being](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sire#examples)' or 'bearing children' -

> Example:
> The King of this place is particularly known to have sired many children, ensuring continuity of his family's rule

If Sire is to refer to '[a respectful form of address for someone of high social status, especially a king](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sire) ' or to 'monitor or command rule over someone / something', then -

> Example:
> "We honestly did not know we had trespassed on your lands, sire"

The word sire is more commonly used to refer to  [a male parent of an animal, especially a horse](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sire)

> Example:
> The Arabian Stallion is famous for having sired many race winning horses